# How to add border radius on react-jdenticon component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, identicon

I have used [react-jdenticon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-jdenticon)

Tried to add border radius but it seems that it can not take the css styling on svg or canvas element.

Any suggestions for this?

```
import React from 'react';
import Jdenticon from 'react-jdenticon';

function Example(){
  return(<Jdenticon size="48" value="Hello World" />);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to customize the css styling on SVG images. I would suggest you to use the `jdenticon` package for this purpose. Using the `jdenticon` build a custom component with the following code. Now you can add the CSS classes or any styling to SVG element which you wants to add.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import jdenticon from 'jdenticon';

const Jdenticon = ({ value = 'test', size = '100%', className }) => {
  const icon = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    jdenticon.update(icon.current, value);
  }, [value]);

  return (
    <div>
      <svg data-jdenticon-value={value} height={size} ref={icon} width={size} className={className} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now for the usage, you can use it in this way.

```
function Usage(){
  return(<Jdenticon size="48" value="Hello World", className="custom-name" />);
}
```

Comment: can we use `import Jdenticon from 'react-jdenticon';` instead of `import jdenticon from 'jdenticon';`

Comment: No basically, now you're using the `jdenticon` library directly. So remove the `react-jdenticon` from your code. And only install the `jdenticon`.

Comment: Can you create another example without using `useRef and useEffect ` ?

Comment: you means using the class components?

Comment: Yes with class components

Comment: Ok I will create it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution works for [jdenticon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jdenticon) package

but is there any solution for [react-jdenticon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-jdenticon) maybe we can extend

```
<Jdenticon size="48" value="Hello World" 'pass classname here'/>
```